# Reflecting on a Moq Object produces 2 additional properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I've got a couple of methods that use reflection to transform from one object type to another.  I'm in the process of testing the transformation methods via Moq and have stumbled upon a behavior I don't know how to handle.  When I reflect across a Moq object to obtain PropertyInfo's, I get two additional objects.

- ``` Moq.Mock``1[Namespace.Class+IElement] Mock ```
- `Moq.Mock Mock`

The code to reproduce this is below:

```
public void Moq_Reflection() {
    var realElement = new Stuff();

    // Produces 2 items
    PropertyInfo[] pInfo = realElement.GetType().GetProperties(); 

    var mockElement = new Mock<IElement>();
    mockElement.Setup(e => e.Property1).Returns(12);
    mockElement.Setup(e => e.Property2).Returns(42);

    // Produces 4 items
    pInfo = mockElement.Object.GetType().GetProperties();
}

public interface IElement { 
    int Property1 { get; set; } 
    int Property2 { get; set; } 
}

public class Stuff : IElement
{
    public int Property1
    {
        get { return -1; }
        set { }
    }

    public int Property2
    {
        get { return -2; }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to Reflect on a Moq object and not retrieve these properties?

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about this more this afternoon, so here's another idea.

If I were coding this in my own project, I'd abstract out the reflection of the object.  I'd create an interface that defines a contract for a class that will return the properties of an object, and then create a class that implements that interface by using reflection to return the set of properties.  Same as what you're probably doing.

But then in the tests, I'd create a new implementation of the interface, but I'd add in whatever rules I needed to filter out unwanted properties on my mock objects.  My live code wouldn't include any of the code necessary for testing.

I just had to get that idea out, just trying to help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the code in LinqPad, and the only solution I could find to cut those two properties out was to exclude them based on whether PropertyType or Name included "Mock".  For example:

```
pInfo.Where(item => item.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("Mock") == false);
pInfo.Where(item => item.Name.Contains("Mock") == false);
```

It's borderline hacky, but it's the only attribute I can find to filter.  I don't think there's a way to filter the reflection itself.

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't have to be that way.  There's nothing uglier than writing code in your main app to compensate for your tests.  Thanks though, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper around the Moq object that implements the desired interface and delegates property access to the Moq object. This way, when you reflect on the wrapper object, you will only see the properties you are interested in.

```
public class ElementWrapper : IElement
{
    private readonly IElement _wrappedElement;

    public ElementWrapper(IElement element)
    {
        _wrappedElement = element;
    }

    public int Property1
    {
        get { return _wrappedElement.Property1; }
        set { _wrappedElement.Property1 = value; }
    }

    public int Property2
    {
        get { return _wrappedElement.Property2; }
        set { _wrappedElement.Property2 = value; }
    }
}
```

Here's how you can modify your Moq_Reflection() method to use the ElementWrapper:

```
public void Moq_Reflection()
{
    var realElement = new Stuff();

    // Produces 2 items
    PropertyInfo[] pInfo = realElement.GetType().GetProperties();

    var mockElement = new Mock<IElement>();
    mockElement.Setup(e => e.Property1).Returns(12);
    mockElement.Setup(e => e.Property2).Returns(42);

    var wrappedElement = new ElementWrapper(mockElement.Object);

    // Produces 2 items
    pInfo = wrappedElement.GetType().GetProperties();
}
```